# Ionic App with Firebase Realtime DB and Node.JS server - Architecture

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, firebase

I am new to development (have very basic HTML/JS knowledge). I have decided to learn and make my first hybrid-app. I have read a lot and watched multiple videos in the past few weeks and was very impressed with the Ionic Framework and Firebase. Can you please help me decide on the architecture of the app?

My Idea: (A realtime location sharing app between groups of friends)

Ionic Front End <--> Firebase <--> Node Server

Where firebase will be the intermediary between the server and the front-end. The Node Server will only be needed to do specific things like Payment Gateway/SMS Authentication via services like Twilio. I will not need the server for anything else. All the heavy-lifting will be done by Firebase. I am planning to store all the user profile data in Firebase when the profiles are created. This data can be updated later as well. The only data that will be updated instantaneously by the users is their current location. I am thinking of storing the entire user profile json table which includes all the user info in localstorage/sqlite on the front end as most of this data is typically not modified. This(Caching) happens only when I first open my app. And typically if there are any changes to the json data the localstore/sqlite will need to be updated based on the changes in Firebase. I am then planning to print to the DOM the user info (10/page) from the localstorage/sqlite and the location info from firebase corresponding to that user.

I wanted to know if I am on the right track with this architecture? I understand firebase is for chat type of applications but I still think this is the best out there as it does all my user authentication etc without much fuss. I would need to define the rules properly in Firebase though.

I would really appreciate if you could give me some guidance.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I recommend reading this [classic blog post on common Firebase application architectures](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html).  From a quick read it sounds like a reasonable architecture. Whether it's the right one, only time can tell. If you run into trouble, post back here and we'll try to help.

Comment: Thank you Frank, for your input. I will run with the idea for now and see how it goes.